# c# check textbox for valid path to folder or file based on checkbox and radio button selection

Tags: c#

I have run into a problem with my checking algorithm that makes sure all the textbox inputs are correct before proceeding to the next step in the code.

**I have 4 textboxes:**

`srcTB` = source of file

`customDestTB` = set a custom path to save file

`defaultDestTB` = chooses the destination directory from the srcTB automatically

`fileNameTB` = name to save the file as + the extension taken from srcTB

**I also have two radio buttons:**

`customDestRB` = user selects this to set their own path in customDestTB

`defaultDestRB` = user selects this to use default path from defaultDestTB

The user can also choose to save a single file with `getFileCB` checkbox or to save a folder of files with `getFolderCB`

**so the process is this:**

The user can choose a source file or a source directory of files, they use the check boxes to check either `getFileCB` or `getFolderCB`.

The user then selects either `customDestRB` or `defaultDestRB` to set the path in either `customDestTB` or `defaultDestTB`

The user types the filename in `fileNameTB` and the extension is added from a `.Split()` that's performed on `srcTB.Text`

The user then clicks a `SAVE` button and the checks begin to ensure all the textboxes are filled out correctly to perform the above actions programmatically. I have been trying to work out how to check if the file/directory path is valid using `File.Exists()` and `Directory.Exists()` but have been unsuccessful in getting it to work as intended

**Here is my code that checks the textboxes:**

```
File.Exists(srcTB.Text) || Directory.Exists(srcTB.Text);

if (customDestRB.Checked == true)
{
    if (getFileCB.Checked == true)
    {
        File.Exists(destTB.Text);
    }
    else if (getFolderCB.Checked == true)
    {
        Directory.Exists(destTB.Text);
    }
}
else if (setDestRB.Checked == true)
{
    if (getFileCB.Checked == true)
    {
        File.Exists(destTB.Text);
    }
    else if (getFolderCB.Checked == true)
    {
        Directory.Exists(destTB.Text);
    }
}
else if (fileNameTB.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check the filename is correct before proceeding", "Failed");
}
else
///Continue with save process
```

My question is, how can I make sure all of the paths supplied in each textbox are valid in the correct way?

**Edit:**

I eventually figured out that the save function had to be called from an if statement with `File.Exists()` to get the result I was looking for.

for anyone who has this problem in future I implemented something like this:

```
//Check customDestRB is checked
if (customDestRB.Checked == true)
{
  //Check getFileCB is checked
  if (getFileCB.Checked == true)
  {
    //Check if the filename is in use
    if (File.Exists(destTB.Text + fileNameTB.Text))
    {
      //If filename is in use then prompt the user to pick another filename
      MessageBox.Show("File already exists, choose another filename");
    }
    //Check if directory exists 
    else if (Directory.Exists(destTB.Text))
    {
      //If it exists,
      //Do something here here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why your current code doesn't work? What is it doing wrong? It'd be useful to show some sample inputs which fail with your current code; including what the code *should* be doing for those particular inputs

Comment: Hi Rob, I have set up richtextbox to log points through out the code and it seems the program just stops at the checking point in the code above and does not progress to the actual saving code which comes after. It should be checking the input from each textbox and making sure that the string in each textbox is a valid path to either a folder or file based on the choices of the radio buttons and the check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
 File.exists(variable) || Directory.exists(variable);
```

You had semicolon before `||`

Comment: typo, have edited the original post. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Didnt see the comment button originally. Noted.